# yes no answer system / game trouble with the if stamtment in python

Tags: python

I want the program to ask a new question depending on the previous question's answer. Several times. I am probably doing it completely wrong (I'm a noob and want to learn)

```
Q1 = input("stripes? answer yes or no: ")
if Q1 == "yes":
    Q2 = input("horizontal stripes? answer yes or no: ")
if Q1 == "no":
    Q3 = input("is there a cross? answer yes or no: ")
if Q2 == "yes":
    Q4 = input("is there 3 difrent colors or more? answer yes or no: ")
if Q2 == "no":
    Q5 = input("dose it have some sort of crest? answer yes or no : ")
if Q3 == "yes":
    Q6 = input("is ther 3 different colors or more? answer yes or no: ")
if Q3 == "no":
    Q7 = input(" is ther a red background color? answer yes or no: ")
```

If I answer the first question no and the second yes it gives me folowing error: 
`NameError: name "Q2" is not defined`.

It worked fine until I added the last 2 ifs.
Thank you for the answers and sorry for bad spelling I have dyslexia.

Comment: What doesn't work? Please take some time to read [help] and [mcve].

Comment: Initialize thus. Q1 = Q2 = Q3 = Q4 = Q5 = Q6 = Q7 = ""

Comment: `Q2` hasn't been initialized if `Q1 == "no"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to read about [conditional statements in python](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Conditional_Statements). There is a very good thing called `else`.
I have rewritten what you have done:

```
Q1 = input("stripes? answer yes or no: ")
if Q1 == "yes":
    Q2 = input("horizontal stripes? answer yes or no: ")
    if Q2 == "yes":
        Q4 = input("is ther 3 difrent colors or more? answer yes or no: ")
    else:
        Q5 = input("dose it have som sort of crest? answer yes or no : ")
else:
    Q3 = input("is ther a cross? answer yes or no: ")
    if Q3 == "yes":
        Q6 = input("is ther 3 difrent colors or more? answer yes or no: ")
    else:
        Q7 = input("is ther a red bakround color? answer yes or no: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error occurs because Q2 hasn't been initialized if you enter 'yes' for Q1 input.  Make use of conditional statements per @pythad's answer.

Further, you can make this a bit more scaleable using a class to represent your questions (presumably part of an order form...).

```
class OrderForm():
    def __init__(self):
        self.questions = {1:"stripes?", 
                          2:"horizontal stripes?",
                          3:"is there a cross? ",
                          4:"is there 3 different colors or more?",
                          5:"does it have some sort of crest?",
                          6:"is there 3 different colors or more?",
                          7:"is there a red background color?"
                          }
        self.responses = {k:'' for k in self.questions.keys()}

    def ask(self, q):
        try:
            a = input(self.questions[q] + " answer yes or no: ")
            a = a.lower().strip()
            self.responses[q] = a if a in ['yes','no'] else ''
        except:
            # no response given
            self.responses[q] = None
        return self.responses[q]

def foo():
    form = OrderForm()
    if not form.ask(1):
        print('Q1 is required...')
        return
    else:
        with form.responses[1] as Q1:
            if Q1 == 'yes':
                form.ask(2)
                if form.responses[2] == 'yes':
                    form.ask(4)
                else:
                    form.ask(5)
            elif Q1 == 'no':
                form.ask(3)
                if form.responses[3] == 'yes':
                    form.ask(6)
                else:
                    form.ask(7)

            print('\n'.join(['Q{} '.format(i) + form.questions[i] + '\t' + form.responses[i] for i in range(1, len(form.questions)+1)]))
```